# Optimizing the frozen graph

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have frozen the tensorflow graph and I have noticed that the using the graph in realtime for prediction is too slow. so I would like to do graph optimization.

Within my project file, I have got a folder called model which contains the model file (pb file).

Now I tried running the following command inside the model dir

 `bazel build tensorflow/python/tools:strip_unused`

But it is firing the following error,

> bazel build tensorflow/python/tools:strip_unused
>   ERROR: no such package 'tensorflow/python/tools': BUILD file not found on package path.

Answer (score 0):

You need to build the tool inside the tensorflow directory, not the model directory, and then run the tool on the model.